# How to get ExecutableValidator? Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, maven

I'm following the Hibernate Validator documentation on how to validate a method but I can't find the ExecutableValidator interface. This import is not recognized

```
import javax.validation.executable.ExecutableValidator;
```

I'm following this example from the documentation [Example 3.10. Obtaining an ExecutableValidator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-method-constraints.html#section-obtaining-executable-validator)

What am I missing?

Project details:

- Maven 3
- Spring 3.2.4 core RELEASE (not MVC)
- Hibernate Validator 5.0.1 Final
- JBoss AS 7.1.1
- Java 7

My Pom.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
          <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
          <groupId>com.sadc</groupId>
          <artifactId>MissionControl</artifactId>
          <packaging>war</packaging>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <name>MissionControl</name>
          <url>http://www.company.co.za</url>

      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>java.net</id>
          <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
          <id>JBoss repository</id>
          <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>

      </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils-bean-collections</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.ext.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.39.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.ext.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>juli</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.39.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
      <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.3.GA</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <hostname>${env.HOSTNAME}</hostname>
          <port>9999</port>
          <username> admin</username>
          <password>adminadmin</password>
          <filename>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</filename>
          <webModule>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <contextRoot>/MissionControl</contextRoot>
          </webModule>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `javax.validation.executable.ExecutableValidator` can be found in the following artifact:
javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final

You don't have this as a dependency in your POM.

Adding the following dependency to your POM should solve your problem:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank You, I thought this should come with the JDK.